# I am adding the div-container class after the header but its being displayed at top of the page

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am adding the div-container class after the header but its being displayed at top of the page.
Basically we are trying to add the class div-container after the header  our doctors  but what happens is it is being displayed else where.
we have base.html and this file extends that [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQJtN.png).

```
    {% extends 'pages/base.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    <section class="home" id="home">
    <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    </div></div>
    <div class="content">
    <h3>we take care of your healthy life</h3>
    <p>Maintaining good health will ultimately lead to a happy mind which is more valuable                               than any precious gift in today’s life. 
                Having a healthy life must be a part of everyone’s lifestyle.
                If one has a healthy and happy mind, then one will always stay motivated towards     one’s work and will be productive at work.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Learn More </a>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- home section ends -->

    <!-- Table section starts  -->
<section class="Table-container">
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="cell">
            <th>
           <td><p class="tooltip">doctors at work<span class="tooltiptext">Top 5 doctors in our hospital.
                1. Dr. Siddhartha Mukherjee – Biologist.
                2. Dr. Naresh Trehan – cardiothoracic surgeon.
                3. Dr. Sudhansu Bhattacharyya – Cardiac surgeon.
                4. Dr.  Surbhi Anand – Endodontist.
                5. Dr. Ashish Sabharwal- Urologist.
                <a href="#">Learn More</a></span></p></td></th>
        </div>
    
        <div class="cell">
            <th>
           <td><p class="tooltip">satisfied patients<span class="tooltiptext">Patients and staff satisfaction is an important component of the health care industry.About the performance of staff, appointment system,behavior of staff,support service and any other suggestions of patients.  <a href="#">Learn More</a></span></p></td></th>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <th>
           <td>
            <p class="tooltip">bed facility<span class="tooltiptext"> A hospital bed specially designed for
                hospitalized patients or others in need of some form of health care. These beds have special features both for the 
                comfort and well-being of the patient and for the convenience of health care workers.
        <a href="#">Learn More</a></span></p></td></th>
        </div>
    
        <div class="cell">
            <th>
           <td>
            <p class="tooltip">available hospitals<span class="tooltiptext">Available hospital are   1. Apollo health city
             2. Kims- Krishna Institute Of Medical Sciences
                3. Sunshine hospitals
                4. Continental hospitals
                5. Medicover Hospitals
                <a href="#">Learn More</a>  
            </span></p></td></th>
        </div>
</section>
<!-- icons section ends -->

<!-- doctors section starts -->

<section class="doctors" id="doctors">

    <h1 class="heading"> our <span>doctors</span> </h1>

    <div class="box-container">

        <div class="box">
            <img src="images/doctor1.jpg" alt="">
            <h3>ABC</h3>
            <span>expert doctor</span>
            <div class="share">
                <a href="#" class="fab fa-facebook-f"></a>
                <a href="#" class="fab fa-twitter"></a>
                <a href="#" class="fab fa-instagram"></a>
                <a href="#" class="fab fa-linkedin"></a>
                
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <img src="images/doctor2.jpg" alt="">
            <h3>DEF</h3>
            <span>expert doctor</span>
            <div class="share">
            <a href="#" class="fab fa-facebook-f"></a>
                <a href="#" class="fab fa-twitter"></a>
                <a href="#" class="fab fa-instagram"></a>
                <a href="#" class="fab fa-linkedin"></a>
                
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <img src="images/doctor3.jpg" alt="">
            <h3>GHI</h3>
            <span>expert doctor</span>
            <div class="share">
            <a href="#" class="fab fa-facebook-f"></a>
                <a href="#" class="fab fa-twitter"></a>
                <a href="#" class="fab fa-instagram"></a>
                <a href="#" class="fab fa-linkedin"></a>
                
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <img src="images/doctor4.jpg" alt="">
            <h3>JKL</h3>
            <span>expert doctor</span>
            <div class="share">
                <a href="#" class="fab fa-facebook-f"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="fab fa-twitter"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="fab fa-instagram"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="fab fa-linkedin"></a>
                    
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <img src="images/doctor5.jpg" alt="">
            <h3>MNO</h3>
            <span>expert doctor</span>
            <div class="share">
                <a href="#" class="fab fa-facebook-f"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="fab fa-twitter"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="fab fa-instagram"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="fab fa-linkedin"></a>
                    
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="images/doctor5.jpg" alt="">
            <h3>PQR</h3>
            <span>expert doctor</span>
            <div class="share">
                <a href="#" class="fab fa-facebook-f"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="fab fa-twitter"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="fab fa-instagram"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="fab fa-linkedin"></a>
                    
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Is this ‘legal’ HTML? The only permitted parent of a th element is a tr for example.

Comment: The first step is to strip out everything until you have a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. Doing that might help you realise the issue yourself. Otherwise, post that minimal example, including a minimal amount of whatever CSS you need to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help you create a more focussed bit of code.